# Can you fit multiple buttons in one grid cell in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a table, and the grid of the table is going to be filled with buttons, Is it possible to fit more than one button in a grid space?

Comment: Not directly, but you can put a Frame in that grid space, then put whatever you want in the Frame.

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can. Put a frame inside the cell, and then you can put whatever you want inside the frame. Inside the frame you can use `pack`, `place` or `grid` since it is independent from the rest of the widgets.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="hello")
l2 = tk.Label(root, text="world")
f1 = tk.Frame(root)
b1 = tk.Button(f1, text="One button")
b2 = tk.Button(f1, text="Another button")

l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
l2.grid(row=0, column=1)
f1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

b1.pack(side="top")
b2.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, your response really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper already provided the answer, but here's some code to go along with it.

This is just a random example with a bunch of buttons / frames using grid / pack. The `pack` for the buttons was arbitrary you could have used `grid` instead Each grid section has a random padx to show that it's in a different column and each different column within the grid contains multiple buttons

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
#Now you want another frame
for i in range(5):
    gridframe = tk.Frame(root)
    for j in range(3):
        tk.Button(gridframe, text="%d%d" % (i, j)).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    gridframe.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped  a lot I really appreciate it.